# The 'og:type' property is required, but not present

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I know this question has been posted and answered several times on Stackoverflow, but I have not managed to solve my problem for about a week now even after going through quite a few answers here. So finally I decided to post a question here.

My Site URL : http://tech.firstpost.com/news-analysis/new-ipad-air-2-likely-to-be-thinner-faster-and-feature-touch-id-sensor-237405.html

If you see in the source, there are all the suggested og tags.

```html
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="New iPad Air 2 likely to be thinner, faster and feature Touch ID sensor - Tech2" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Apple is expected to unveil the next generation of iPads this week, but looks like tipsters are determined to reveal much of what&#039;s in store even before th - Tech2" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://tech.firstpost.com/news-analysis/new-ipad-air-2-likely-to-be-thinner-faster-and-feature-touch-id-sensor-237405.html" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Tech2" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/tech2dotcom" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2014-10-14T10:35:02+05:30" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2014-10-14T10:39:42+05:30" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2014-10-14T10:39:42+05:30" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://stech3.firstpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/apple_ipad_air_5_281150302632_640x360.jpg" />
```

However, when I check on the FB share debugger it says

1) The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
2) The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

But when I rescrape from the debugger, it fetches everything properly.

This site runs on wordpress. I work for 3 other sites that use similar facebook share feature and the corresponding tags. None of them ever seem to have any issues at all. On this site too, it was working until a few days back. But suddenly, on **random** articles it does not work.

I have read in some answers that I need to add the **fb:app_id**, but I dont think it is compulsory. None of my other sites use this and still everything seems to work fine.

Any help will be really appreciated. This one has been a total bummer and I am not able to get around it.

Thank you in advance

EDIT :-

```html
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="New iPad Air 2 likely to be thinner, faster and feature Touch ID sensor - Tech2" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Apple is expected to unveil the next generation of iPads this week, but looks like tipsters are determined to reveal much of what&#039;s in store even before th - Tech2" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://tech.firstpost.com/news-analysis/new-ipad-air-2-likely-to-be-thinner-faster-and-feature-touch-id-sensor-237405.html" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Tech2" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/tech2dotcom" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Apple" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="iPad" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="iPad Air 2" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="ipad air 2 features" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="ipad air 2 leaks" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="ipad air 2 release" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="ipad launch october" />
<meta property="article:section" content="News &amp; Analysis" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2014-10-14T10:35:02+05:30" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2014-10-14T10:39:42+05:30" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2014-10-14T10:39:42+05:30" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://stech3.firstpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/apple_ipad_air_5_281150302632_640x360.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@tech2eets"/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="Tech2"/>
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@tech2eets"/>
```

These r all the tags i use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess og:type will be website  `<meta property="og:type"   content="website" />` or you can review the og:type from from http://ogp.me/#no_vertical

**No Vertical**

These are globally defined objects that just don't fit into a vertical but yet are broadly used and agreed upon.

og:type values:

- article - Namespace URI: http://ogp.me/ns/article#
- article:published_time - datetime - When the article was first published.
- article:modified_time - datetime - When the article was last changed.
- article:expiration_time - datetime - When the article is out of date after.
- article:author - profile array - Writers of the article.
- article:section - string - A high-level section name. E.g. Technology
- article:tag - string array - Tag words associated with this article.

Comment: try change `<meta property="og:type" content="article" />`  to `<meta property="og:type" content="website" />`